# AC issue after repairs

Tags: ford, ac, f-350

2005 F350 Dually Diesel, had compressor clutch assembly and e-vap core replaced today, as well as a restrictor and 3 “0” rings.drove approximately 30 miles, and when we stopped and put in park (still running) heard what sounded like a steam valve opening, and quite a bit smoke?(white) billowed from under truck, big cloud. AC now considerably less cool.

Answer (score 3):

What looked like smoke will have been the refrigerant leaking from your air conditioning.  It will have created the steam noise too, since it will have leaked under high pressure.

It is possible that this is just a coincidence, a pipe or the condenser was corroded and ready to leak.  However the mechanic may have had to remove or move some of the AC components to get access to do the necessary work and may have caused some damage.

You need to take it back and get them to identify where it is leaking from.